# Can we use Entity Framework Core in .NET Framework ASP.NET Web API? If so how?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I want to change ORM of an existing old .NET Web API application from Telerik Openaccess ORM to Entity Framework.

Should I go with Entity Framework 6 or use the latest Entity Framework Core? Not sure if EF Core will work with Web API in the full/classic .NET Framework

Comment: EF Core for sure. EF 6 is slow and currently just in support mode - only bug fixing.

Comment: EF Core 3.1 works with .NET Framework 4.7.2 or later

Comment: I am using .NET Framework 4.5.2 in my project. What version of EF Core will work on that

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/platforms From what is stated here in this doc. It seems its not supported with 4.5.2